# Sequence of holomorphic functions converges uniformly, but sequence of $k^{th}$ derivatives doesn't

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Is there a sequence of holomorphic functions $(f_{n})$ on the closed unit disc such that $(f_{n})$ converges uniformly to a holomorphic function $f$ on the closed unit disc, but $(f_{n}^{(k)})$ does not converhe uniformly to $(f^{(k)})$ for some $k\geq 1?$

I know that this property is true is we consider a disc of radius strictly less than $1$ which we view as a subset of the closed unit disc, but I cannot find an example for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f_n(z)=\frac {z^{n}} n$ is such an example. [$k=1, f\equiv 0$].